# how to get a certificate's fingerprint from a 509 certificate attribute from saml response in CLI

Tags: macos, openssl, x509certificate, saml-2.0

From a SAML response, I need to find the certificate's fingerprint from the `<ds:X509Certificate>` attribute of the response.

Similar to how I'd get it from https://www.samltool.com/fingerprint.php but from CLI instead.

I found there is a way to get it from certificate file like https://www.jvt.me/posts/2019/04/03/openssl-fingerprint-x509-pem/ but not from the response.

Comment: Quick hack , you could extract the certificate 'text' via xpath and provide an output file for 'keytool'
`xpath SAMLResponse.xml '//Assertion//Signature//KeyInfo//X509Certificate/text()' | awk '{printf "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n%s\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n", $1}'`

Comment: Just so you're aware... There's no requirement to include the certificate in a response.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you have the SAMLResponse (base64 encoded) in `$SAMLRESPONSE`:

```
echo "$SAMLRESPONSE" | base64 -D | xpath -q -e '//Assertion//Signature//KeyInfo//X509Certificate/text()' ~/tmp/samlresponse.xml| awk '{printf "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n%s\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n", $1}'| $(brew --prefix openssl)/bin/openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint
SHA1 Fingerprint=9B:47:78:9B:2B:1C:90:09:F7:85:85:1A:18:4E:A0:26:EC:FA:1D:4E
```

The above script

- Uses `base64 -D` to decode the the SAMLResponse into the XML
- Uses `xpath` to extract the X509Certificate,
- uses `awk` to wrap that with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` so that it becomes PEM compliant
- Uses openssl (but not the openssl/LibreSSL that comes with macOS, it has to be a version installed with Homebrew) to load that X509 in PEM format and compute the fingerprint